# Is there are way to create a generic class with a trait or mixin that is a subtype of the type parameter

Tags: scala, generics, traits, scalaz, type-constructor

I am trying to attach extra data to other types, and have a trait similar to:

```
trait ExtraData {
  def getExtraData() : Array[Byte]
}
```

And I'm currently using it like this:

```
class ExternalType1WithExtraData(superType:ExternalType1, bytes:Array[Byte]) extends ExternalType1(superType.a,superType.b, ...) with ExtraData {
  def getExtraData() : Array[Byte] = bytes
}

class ExternalType2WithExtraData(superType:ExternalType2, bytes:Array[Byte]) extends ExternalType2(superType.z,superType.w, ...) with ExtraData {
  def getExtraData() : Array[Byte] = bytes
}
```

It seems like there would be a generic way to create these classes, but I haven't been able to find it yet.

--- Begin Edit -- Adding desired behavior

Given a function

```
def sendData(ex : ExternalType1)
```

I want to be able to pass my enhanced types to that function.

```
val data:ExternalType1 = ???
val moredata:ExternalType1 = { new ExternalType1 with ExtraData{...} }
sendData(moredata)
```

--- End Edit

I've tried to do things along these lines but have had no success:

```
// Compiler wont let me extend T
class WithExtraData[T](bytes:Array[Byte]) extends T with ExtraData{
  def getExtraData() : Array[Byte] = bytes
}
```

> :12: error: class type required but T found
>          class WithExtraDataT extends T with ExtraData{
>                                                            ^
>   :12: error: illegal inheritance; supertype T
>    is not a subclass of the superclass Object
>    of the mixin trait ExtraData
>          class WithExtraDataT extends T with ExtraData{

```
// Seems closer, but doesn't work.
class WithExtraData[T](t:T, bytes:Array[Byte]) extends ExtraData {
  this : T => t
  def getExtraData() : Array[Byte] = bytes
}
```

> :13: warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position; multiline expressions may require enclosing parentheses
>                self : T => t
>                            ^
>   defined class WithExtraData
>
> scala> new WithExtraData[String]("hi", new ArrayByte)
>   :13: error: class WithExtraData cannot be instantiated because it does not conform to its self-type WithExtraData[String] with String

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I am guessing that you are omitting an important requirement. Are you trying to extend  `ExternalType1` so that you can pass this instance to some external library, get it back, cast to `ExtraData` and then `getExtraData`? If not, you should definitely stay away from subclassing.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do something quite similar to that, but to Kryo with custom serializers.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the closest you can reasonably get (at least without macros) is not to extend `ExternalType1`, but to have an implicit conversion instead:

```
class WithExtraData[T](val value: T, bytes: Array[Byte]) extends ExtraData {
  def getExtraData(): Array[Byte] = bytes
}

object WithExtraData {
  implicit def getValue[T](x: WithExtraData[T]): T = x.value
}
```

Then you can e.g. pass `WithExtraData[ExternalType1]` whenever `ExternalType1` is required.

Comment: From my understanding, that would cause the "extraData" to be ripped off and not actually be passed along.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "ripped off". I was going to suggest simply `type WithExtraData[A] = (A, Array[Byte])` as a further refinement to this solution, but I believe this doesn't solve the problem you are actually trying to solve.

Comment: Yes, I want to still be able to pass the WithExtraData[T] to functions that operate on T.

Answer (score 0):

You basically try to enrich your types with additional type information represented by values if I understand you correct? In that case, the concept you looking for is called [Dependent Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type)

Scala does not support this concept natively (like for example Idris). However, there are some workarounds to get closer.

One example would be to use Shapeless

```
import shapeless._
import SingletonTypes._

val test1: ^((20 + 50) > 1) = true
test1: Boolean(true) = true

val test2: ^((20 + 50) > 1) = false
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Boolean(false)
 required: Boolean(true)
```

Comment: Very cool! - However I'm wanting the extra data to be instance specific.